# Fit poisson distribution to data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, poisson

I have plotted a histogram and would like to fit a poisson distribution to the histogram. To do this, I have passed the x and y histogram coordinate vector to the `poissfit()` function to estimate lambda.

For example, here is what I've done:

```
expecteddata = cat(2,x,y)
[l,lci] = poissfit(expecteddata)
```

My output looks like so:

```
l =

   44.3766    0.0130


lci =

   42.8887    0.0003
   45.8645    0.0724
```

I'm assuming the the lambda I'm interested in for plotting would be `0.013` (I think my lambda is so small because my histogram is a frequency histogram). I plot the poisson pdf using:

```
x = 0:50
y = poisspdf(x,0.013);
plot(x,y,'r')
```

And I get the resulting overlayed plot:

[image]

However, I think this fitted distribution looks a little odd. It doesn't appear to be very "poisson" like. Does anyone know if I'm doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: I think your x range is too large (i.e. the data step size is too big, so you are not seeing the finesse of the distribution), 0:50 while your lambda is at 0.013, maybe try something like 0:0.01:10 and see if the result is better.

Comment: @GameOfThrows instead of using `x = 0:50`, I actually used the x values from my histogram.

Comment: yes, I think that is too low resolution (if you know what I mean) for your distribution to look right, you really want higher resolution so something like 0:0.01:10.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I also tried your method. Unfortunately, It produced an ever odder result.

Comment: I guess my distribution doesn't really fit the poisson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have plotted a histogram and would like to fit a poisson distribution to the histogram."

What I understand is you need to fit poisson distribution to a existing histogram of measured data. I believe you can use the `fitdist()` function.

For example, if your data is `x`.

```
[n,bin]=hist(x,100);
m=n/trapz(bin,n);
bar(bin,m,'w');
hold on
pd=fitdist(x,'poisson');
y=pdf(pd,bin);
plot(bin,y,'k');
hold off;
```

will give you a histogram with a poisson distributed curve fitted to it.

Comment: Ohhhhh. I see my problem. I was using the frequency for the x in `fitdist` when I should have been using the data before I calculated the frequency.